# How to change default bullet in beamer to a simple dash

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

I would like to change the default bullet style for the itemize environment in beamer to be a dash (or double dash).
It seems that labelitemi is not defined in beamer so

```
\renewcommand\labeli{-}
```

does not work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{--}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}    
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]